# Power BI: how to remove top 20% of values from an average

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm working with call center data and looking to calculate the average ring time of calls while removing the highest 20% of ring times. I assume I'll need to use PERCENTILEX.EXC embedded somewhere in AVERAGE, but I'm not quite sure where, or if I'm totally off base. 2 other caveats on this are that there are calls answered immediately (queue time = 0) which have to be counted in the average time and only data where the disposition column = Handled are used.

Example:

[image: Node ID Disposition Queue Time 46002139683 Handled 0 46002139683 Handled 0 46002138955 Handled 1 46002135883 Handled 1 46002135907 Handled 2 46002135933 Handled 2 46002136382 Handled 2 46002136382 Handled 3 46002136558 Handled 3 46002136562 Handled 4 46002136734 Aborted 4 46002136875 Abandon 4 46002136938 Handled 5 46002136982 Handled 5 46002137006 Handled 5 46002137018 Handled 5 46002137022 Handled 5 46002126126 Handled 5 46002126207 Handled 5 46002126500 Handled 6 46002126500 Handled 9 46002126782 Handled 14]

The Aborted and Abandoned call would be filtered out. Of the remaining calls, the top 20% of queue times (the 14,9, 6, and one of the 5s) would be eliminated and the average would be 3 seconds.

Appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
VAR totalRows = COUNTROWS(FILTER(table, table[disposition] = "Handled"))
VAR bottomN = ROUNDDOWN(totalRows * .8, 0)

RETURN AVERAGEX(TOPN(bottomN, FILTER(table, table[disposition] = "Handled"), table[queue time], ASC),table[queue time])
```